# Understanding closures in scala

Tags: scala, closures

I am newbie to Scala. I have a method just as below :

```
def process(func: Context => T) = {
  val context = getContext() // This method provides me the context
  func(context)
}
```

Now if I want to call this method. I have two helper methods

```
def runContext1(context: Context): String = {
   "hello world"
}

def runContext2(): (Context) => String = {
  context => "hello world"
}

def test1() = {
  process(context => { 
   "hello world"
  })
}

def test2() = {
  process(runContext1)
}

def test3() = {
  process(runContext2())
}
```

`test2()` does not work and throws a `NullPointerException` whereas `test3()` works.

1. Differences between test1(), test2() and test3() // As per my understanding test1() uses closure with anonymous functions. test2() and test3() are closures with named functions. Correct me if I am wrong and tell me if there are other differences
2. I want to know why `test3()` works and `test2()` does not.
3. What is the contract of `runContext2()`? I do not understand `runContext2(): (Context) => String`.

Comment: Neither `context1` nor `context2` are defined in the code you've shown.

Comment: @sepp2k Sorry. I have updated

Comment: If I add the missing definitions and fix the syntax error in order to make your code compile, it runs without error. Therefore your problem is in the code you didn't show.

Comment: @sepp2k Yeah the internal implementations are huge. So are you telling that test3() and test2() are just the same. And could you explain the contract of runContext2()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is somewhere in the implementation of `test2` method. All of the code you posted should work (except for the fact that `test1()` is missing a closing parenthesis, but that's a typo).

Regarding your first question, yes, you are right in sense that those are closures because they "close over" definitions of `process`, `runContext1` and `runContext2`. Whenever a method uses something defined outside of its scope, that's a closure. If that value changes on the outside, method will see that change. Further reading: [link](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functions-and-closures.html#8.7). And yes, `test1` uses an anonymous function, while `test2` and `test3` use named ones.

Now, about your third question. The thing is, `runContext2()` is a *method taking nothing and returning a function*. Returned function takes a context and returns a string. It could have been a `val` too (in that case you would of course need to omit the empty parenthesis since vals don't take arguments):

```
val runContextVal: (Context) => String = {
  context => "hello world"
}
```

Note that your method `process()` takes a function, so in fact our `runContextVal` would be the only one actually obeying the contract when passed to `process` method:

```
process(runContextVal)
```

All other invocations of process() have a **method** passed to it (defined using keyword def) instead of a function. This is not something compiler would allow per se. However, it's smart enough to perform something called *eta expansion* which is basically a simple transformation of a parameterless method into a function. Key idea is fairly simple - every value, e.g. 42 or "foo", can be thought of as a function which takes nothing and returns that value, e.g. `() => 42`. Furthermore, a function that takes a parameter (such as `val f = (x: Int) => Int`) can be thought of as a function that takes a parameter and returns your function applied to that parameter (e.g. `(x: Int) => f(x)`). Function for squaring numbers (let's call it sqr()) is the same as a function n => sqr(n), isn't it? Check out some other online materials for extra details (e.g. [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion), [here](https://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/functional-scala-turning-methods-into-functions/) or [here](http://blog.jaceklaskowski.pl/2013/11/23/how-much-one-ought-to-know-eta-expansion.html)).

Note however that if you wanted to create a function value from your `runContext1` method, you would run into trouble:

```
val fun2 = runContext2 // works
val fun1 = runContext1 // ERROR!
```

*If a method is parameterless or has an empty parameter* ([not the same thing](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/composition-and-inheritance.html#10.3)), then eta-expansion is performed automatically. However, *if it has one or more actual parameters* (like `runContext1` has `Context`) then we need to give the compiler a hand. We either need to explicitly state the value type:

```
val fun1: Context => String = runContext1
```

or make a [partially applied function](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functions-and-closures.html#8.6):

```
val fun1 = runContext1 _
```

If this is all new to you, don't be overwhelmed. Just write methods like you normally would (e.g. how `runContext1` is written) and use eta expansion only when (if?) you need it.